# How to keep both the ionic 3 and ionic 4 version together in my machine

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3, ionic4

I am working with ionic 3 version with many apps and it's working fine. Now for my new project, I want to develop in ionic 4 but don't want to uninstall ionic 3. So when I run below command to install ionic 4 locally it throws an error.

Command:

```
npm install ionic@rc cordova
```

Error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ionic@rc
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2019-03-04T09_28_35_725Z-debug.log
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: dont install `cli` globally, install it locally in a project whether to use 3 or 4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to have different versions. You only install the global CLI. The CLI works with all versions of the framework.

eg
https://github.com/ionic-team/starters

run

```
ionic start myApp tabs --type ionic1  // for ionic 1    
ionic start myApp tabs --type ionic-angular // for ionic 2/3    
ionic start myApp tabs --type angular  // for ionic 4+
```

Comment: getting this error :
"[ERROR] Cannot perform Ionic serve/watch for project type: angular.
 If you'd like the CLI to try to detect your project type, you can unset 
  the type attribute in ionic.config.json."  while running ionic serve for ionic 4

Comment: do you have the latest cli version? this error occurred in beta version

Comment: This is my ionic info :

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1) 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : not installed

System:

    Node : v8.11.3
    npm  : 5.6.0 
    OS   : macOS

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro

Comment: latest is: ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.10.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189385/discussion-between-itdoesntwork-and-priyank).

Answer (score 1):

This error shows that there is no existing rc version of ionic.

Try with this.

```
$ npm install -g ionic
```

Comment: so do i need to run above command and then run this 'npm install -g ionic@rc cordova'